# React Modal was working when I went to bed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I had a properly working `react-modal` and all I have been doing since then is adding styling to the application.

Now my button to bring up modal does not work.

I have looked in the two files where the problem could lie.

DecisionTreeApp.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import AddOption from './AddOption';
import Header from './Header';
import Action from './Action';
import Options from './Options';
import OptionModal from './OptionModal';

export default class DecisionTreeApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    options: [],
    selectedOption: undefined
  };
  handleDeleteOptions = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      options: []
    }));
  };
  handleDeleteOption = optionToRemove => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      options: prevState.options.filter(option => optionToRemove !== option)
    }));
  };

  handleClearSelectedOption = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({ selectedOption: undefined }));
  };

  handlePick = () => {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
    const option = this.state.options[randomNum];
    this.setState(() => ({
      selectedOption: option
    }));
  };

  handleAddOption = option => {
    if (!option) {
      return 'Enter valid value to add item';
    } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
      return 'This option already exists';
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      options: prevState.options.concat(option)
    }));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const json = localStorage.getItem('options');
      const options = JSON.parse(json);

      if (options) {
        this.setState(() => ({ options }));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Do nothing at all
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.options.length !== this.state.options.length) {
      const json = JSON.stringify(this.state.options);
      localStorage.setItem('options', json);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('componentWillUnmount');
  }
  render() {
    const subtitle = 'For binary life decisions, put your trust in a computer';

    return (
      <div>
        <Header subtitle={subtitle} />
        <div className="container">
          <Action
            hasOptions={this.state.options.length > 0}
            handlePick={this.handlePick}
          />
          <div className="widget">
            <Options
              options={this.state.options}
              handleDeleteOptions={this.handleDeleteOptions}
              handleDeleteOption={this.handleDeleteOption}
            />
            <AddOption handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <OptionModal
          selectedOption={this.state.selectedOption}
          handleClearSelectedOption={this.handleClearSelectedOption}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or OptionModal.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const OptionModal = (props) => (
  <Modal
    isOpen={!!props.selectedOption}
    onRequestClose={props.handleClearSelectedOption}
    contentLabel="Selected Option"
    closeTimeoutMS={200}
    className="modal"
  >
    <h3>Selected Option</h3>
    {props.selectedOption && <p>{props.selectedOption}</p>}
    <button onClick={props.handleClearSelectedOption}>Okay</button>
  </Modal>
);

export default OptionModal;
```

I do not see any syntax errors in any of the code above. Do any of you see syntax errors?

In the console I am getting this warning:

**Warning: React does not recognize the `Click` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `click` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.**

but I don't believe I have used a `Click` props anywhere in my code. I even looked for one and I don't see it.

When I use react dev tools and inspect **state**, I don't see a change when I press the button, just when I add the choices:

[image]

This is my `Action.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';

const Action = (props) => (
  <div>
    <button
      className="big-button"
      onClick={props.handlePick}
      disabled={!props.hasOptions}
    >
      What should I do?
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default Action;
```

Comment: Is it possible the warning could be a red herring? Depending on what IDE you use could you maybe look at the history of your changes and see if you accidentally changed anything between it working and now

Comment: @Geraint, I think the warning is a red herring, but I have looked over the code and I do not see what I have accidentally changed. I am looking for stuff like accidentally changing `onSubmit` to `Submit`, but I don't see any errors like that.

Comment: Install, if you haven't already React dev tools. Inspect the state/props of the app when you press the button and see if it is changing as you'd expect.

Comment: @Geraint, I added the results of your suggestion to the OP.

Comment: It's a little difficult help anymore with the code that has been shared but I would stick a break point in `handleAddOption` to see if that is getting called - make sure the component `Action` is doing what you expect

Comment: @Geraint, ahh! The component `Action.js` is what has the `Click` that the warning is warning about. It should be `onClick`. So it was not a red herring after all. It was the problem the whole time.

Comment: @Ale, can you post the code to your `Action.js` file?

Comment: @Daniel, I added my `Action.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing how your `Action.js` works. From what you shared, `Action.js` rendered your `big-button`. It needed two props in order for it to work. It needed `handlePick` and `hasOptions`. `hasOptions` appears to be the boolean letting the button know whether it was enabled or in your case `disabled`.

`handlePick` was the function

```
handlePick = () => {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
    const option = this.state.options[randomNum];
    this.setState(() => ({
      selectedOption: option
    }));
  };
```

whose job it was to pick an item at random and show it to the modal.

I would have focused in on these, assuming you understood well what they did. In your case, once you did take a look at the `Actions.js` file, you noticed that your event handler for `handlePick` had a typo in it.

Again, getting to know how each of your components work is essential for effective troubleshooting.